# In which method or event handler if I would to customize in Application tab Menu in screen Bills And Adjustments of Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need to customize business logic of screen Bills and Adjustments (AP301000) of Acumatica ERP. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

I just need to know, in which method or event handlers of APInvoiceEntry should I check if I need to customize of Application Tab Menu from this screen. ?

I need to know the filter condition while system showing all records, regarding of current vendor in application tab menu.

Maybe if anyone know about my questions.

Comment: What do you want to change???

Comment: I need to add/remove additional filter in showing all records in this application tab menu.  By default, system will show all records based on Prepayment has been paid in check and payment screen. And also prepayment already applied to specific bill but still has outstanding amount either of bill or prepayment. I need to remove filter for this outstanding amount, so if prepayment has been applied for specific bill, this prepayment has not been appear when system load all records.

Answer (score 0):

The information is shown from the following `PXSelectJoin` object:

```
public PXSelectJoin<
        APAdjust, 
            InnerJoin<APPayment, 
                On<APPayment.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjgDocType>,
                And<APPayment.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr>>>>> 
        Adjustments;
```

So if you want to change filter conditions you will have to define your own select statement with that additional filtering and set the `DataMember` of that Grid to your defined Select Statement.